# Border background image will not span entire border

Tags: wpf, user-controls, background-image

I am writing a WPF application.  In the application I have a grid that has two columns.  The one column has a border tag that, when the application runs, spans the height of the main window with no issues.

The problem that I am running into is that I want a background image to also span the height of the application and be contained within the border.  When I run the application, however, it only takes up enough space to provide background for the controls that exist on the page.  This means that more than half of that grid column remains white.  I have tried stretching the image (set the stretch to fill) and I know that the image is large enough.

Please, how can I achieve what I am looking for?

Here is the important XAML:

```
<Border>
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Assets/control bg.png" Stretch="Fill" />
        </Border.Background>
        <Grid Margin="10,10,10,0">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush />
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Owner Information" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="21.333" Foreground="#FF2B2B2B" FontFamily="Verdana"/>
            </Border>
            <Grid Margin="10,10,5,5" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          </Grid>
```

The grid does contain some controls which I have left out.  They are just textboxes and combos.

Comment: Try setting a background color (not image) and see if it fills.  Your image may be preserving it's aspect ratio.  Put a color on you border and be sure you border is filling.

Comment: I copied your xaml into an empty Page, put a couple of missing closing tags on and changed the image to a random .png.  Works perfectly.  It maybe something you left out of the xaml above.

Answer (score 0):

Snowbear is right your XAML would be very helpful but here are some things to start off with:

By default, rows and columns in `Grid`s take up the least amount of space necessary to accommodate the largest content within any cell contained in a given row or column. For example, if a column has one cell with a long word like "hippopotamus" contained within it but all the other cells in the column have smaller words like "dog", the width of the column will be the width of the largest word (hippopotamus). "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx"

So, if your border doesn't have an explicit height and width assigned to it then it will exist just around the content you provided in the column. Binding to a set value would work as well.

```
<Grid Height="50" Width="50">
```